# is supportablerange type graph in Highchart?

Tags: highcharts

Can I set a y axis labels as ["1-10","10-20","20-30","30-40","40-50","50-60"] and bar data depends on these range.
Can you please provide us a JSfiddle demo here?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can. Simply use `categories` on yAxis, and normalize values before rendering chart. For example: http://jsfiddle.net/2x0w7jyu/

```
var normalizedData = [0, 0, 1, 5, 4, 3, 2, 2, 5]

$('#container').highcharts({
  yAxis: {
    categories: ["1-10", "10-20", "20-30", "30-40", "40-50", "50-60"]
  },
  series: [{
    name: 'Tokyo',
    data: normalizedData
  }]
});
```